# Distinct on two columns, how to rid from 'duplicates'

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a table with messages, that have 'msg_from' and 'msg_to' fields.

when I want to select all current chats and last message from each of them I use the following query:

```
select distinct on (msg_from, msg_to) array[msg_from, msg_to] 
as participants from mockdata_messages
order by msg_from, msg_to DESC
```

example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1Bttz4i9Cd5RVA9qCpNkH/1

This works fine in Postgres 12

The problem is that I get 'duplicates' in response. I mean, 'participants' values like: [2, 5] and [5, 2], which obviously refers to the same chat.

I got exactly simillar result when I tried to use 'group by' with two columns.
How can I get arround this problem? What approaches are well to use for storing chat messages in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this simple example you can use the least and greatest functions to make the distinct on condition match in both cases.

```
select distinct on ( least(msg_from, msg_to),greatest(msg_from, msg_to)) 
array[msg_from, msg_to] as participants from mockdata_messages
order by least(msg_from, msg_to),greatest(msg_from, msg_to)
```